# ORACLE how to find partial month

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to find a month which is incomplete in ORACLE? For example, I have a column called `month_str` in table A, this `month_str` is from 1/1/2014 to 3/13/2014, thus Jan and Feb are complete months, and March is incomplete. Do you know how to find the incomplete one? Thank you!

The month_str data type is varchar2.

Comment: And the datatype of the column is..?

Comment: Can the start date also be an incomplete month and would you want to find it as well? For example, if month_str is from 1/10/2014 to 3/13/2014, would you have two incomplete months (Jan and Mar)?

Comment: The start month is always the 1st day in a month

Comment: @typeofprogrammer According to which answer you accepted, you need to rephrase your question, because in it's current form it seems unrelated with the answer. Maybe something like `I want to find current month` or `month of the current date`. What `sysdate` has to do with your column data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, the incomplete month will be the current month

Look up SYSDATE

Comment: The question itself is not the example of clearness and sense. But despite of the fact that OP has accepted your answer, it doesn't really answers original question in it's current form.

Comment: Yes it does, you have no guarantee there is a table entry for every day of the month; the only month which is guaranteed to be incomplete is the current one. The question asks how to find the incomplete month, not list the complete ones or months in which there are missing entries for certain days. Sometimes people ask complicated questions with really simple answers :-). They are often what is called [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> with t (month_str) as (
  2  select rownum - 1 + trunc(sysdate,'YEAR')
  3  from dual connect by level <= 72
  4  )
  5  select to_char(max(month_str),'MON YYYY')
  6  from t
  7  group by trunc(month_str,'MM')
  8  having max(month_str) != last_day(max(month_str))
  9  /

TO_CHAR(MAX(MONTH                                                               
-----------------                                                               
MAR 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm) function that will do this for you.

```
select extract(month from sysdate) from dual
```